# cannot open chrome settings or downloads page with Jmeter/Selenium/Java

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter, selenium-chromedriver

Tried to open the downloads page in Chrome with Selenium/JMeter/Java and getting an unsupported protocol error when trying to open the page. What am I missing? Thanks!

Please note: opening web HTTP/S protocol works fine for me, this question is specific for when trying to open .get("chrome://... with Selenium/JMeter/Java

```
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
WDS.browser.get("chrome://downloads/");
```

error is:

```
Response message:unknown protocol: chrome
```

Answer (score 0):

My expectation is that the request itself succeeds, JMeter just fails to properly populate the request results, in particular it should fail [at this line](https://github.com/undera/jmeter-plugins-webdriver/blob/master/src/main/java/com/googlecode/jmeter/plugins/webdriver/sampler/WebDriverSampler.java#L90):

```
res.setURL(new URL(getWebDriver().getCurrentUrl()));
```

Because JMeter's [SampleResult.setURL()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#setURL-java.net.URL-) function expects a valid [URL](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) and `chrome://downloads` is not something which is accepted.

You can "tell" JMeter to ignore this error by adding a [Response Assertion](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/response-assertions-in-jmeter-32-new-and-improved/) as a child of this request and configuring it like:

[image]

This way JMeter will execute the sampler and it will be "green" despite the exception hence the error will not show up in the report and you will still be able to measure the response time:

[image]